# RHEVM 3.1.0 + ipa 4.2.0 domain authentification

Tags: freeipa, ovirt, rhev

There are good working RHEVM 3.1.0. There are external domains? wich added to RHEVM for authorization for distribution rights in RHEVM. Domains are ipa (3.0) and windows. Everything is working.

Now I have added ipa domain version 4.2.0. Domain added, but when I try to add a user from the ipa in rhevm web, domain user search returns nothing.

I also tried to add user in console:

```
 # engine-manage-domains -action=edit -domain='my.domain' -user=admin -provider=ipa --add-permission
The domain my.domain has been added to the engine as an authentication source but no users from that domain have been granted permissions within the oVirt Manager.
Users from this domain can be granted permissions from the Web administration interface.
oVirt Engine restart is required in order for the changes to take place (service ovirt-engine restart).
Manage Domains completed successfully
```

Questions:

Are queries to the domain logging on RHEVM?
If so, where is log file?

Maybe this is incompatible versions of ipa and rhevm (ovirt)?

Some another ideas?

Comment: Open a case with Red Hat.

Comment: Already told you that on LOR. I guess you're running unlicensed and have no support - then either purchase it or switch to oVirt